# For Loop, ArrayList

Tags: java, android, for-loop, arraylist

this might be a very very simple question, im new to java and i got an
 annoying problem, let me try to describe my problem.

When a user selects my listview item, the for loop returns the title of that selected item. Now when the user selects another one, while having the last selected item still selected, the app returns something like:

```
> Item1 // for one item selected

> Item2 // when 2 items are selected
> Item2
> Item2
```

And now what i want the result to be like for 3 selected items:

```
Item1 
Item2
Item3
```

Perhaps its my code or the ListView, but .. i wouldnt know hehe. Thanks for the looksie./

```
int count = lv.getCheckedItemCount;
 SelectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
 for(int i = 0; i< count; i++){
 SelectedItems.add(somevalue);

 }
 for(String test : SelectedItems){
 Log.d("String of SI", test);
  }
```

Comment: Please don't name a variable with a first letter with upper case (`SelectedItems`), the convention is variables start with lower case (`selectedItems`)

Comment: hmm would this cause my problem??

Comment: No, that's why it's a comment, not an answer - but it will make you a better java programmer (sticking to conventions really helps!), and will help people understand your code when looking at it.

Comment: Okay, thanks ill try to live by this rule.

Comment: @sadasd: what do you mean by `somevalue` ?

Comment: What 'somevalue' are you adding to the SelectedItems? Can you provide the complete code of your related to the given code?

Comment: So, 'somevalue' never change in your SelctedItems list?

Comment: @sadasd: why not using `SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();` to get selected rows from ListView?

Answer (score 0):

you have to check if the Object is in the array before putting it inside because two arraylist can contains 2 times the Same Value/Object

```
int count = lv.getCheckedItemCount;
 selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
 for(int i = 0; i< count; i++){
if(!selectedItems.contains(somevalue) 
SelectedItems.add(somevalue);

 }
 for(String test : selectedItems){
 Log.d("String of SI", test);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you must do verify if somevalue exists or not in a selectedItems ArrayList.
You must to put somevalue in Arraylist IF somevalue doesn't exist in it.

so:

```
int count = lv.getCheckedItemCount;
List selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
     if(!selectedItems.contains(somevalue))    
           selectedItems.add(somevalue);    
 }
 for(String test : selectedItems){
 Log.d("String of SI", test);
  }
```